# TCL list the relative path of running script

Tags: path, tcl, relative-path

I look for a code for saving the current path of running tcl script. Ive found already a code but it doesnt works.

```
proc getScriptDirectory {} {
    set dispScriptFile [file normalize [info script]]
    set scriptFolder [file dirname $dispScriptFile]
    return $scriptFolder
}
```

has anybody an idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `info script` command works, but only when the *script* is running and not when the procedures it creates are running. You have to save the value when the code runs so that you can use it later.

```
# The two-argument version of [variable] initialises the variable's value
variable dispScriptFile [file normalize [info script]]

proc getScriptDirectory {} {
    variable dispScriptFile
    set scriptFolder [file dirname $dispScriptFile]
    return $scriptFolder
}
```

There's not usually a significant problem with variable pollution when doing it this way as you can use a variable in the namespace that you're defining, and almost always when you want this you are defining a namespace.

Comment: sorry, i explained it very bad. The script already finished his work. At the End of this scripct i wanna save the current path in a variable..

Comment: `info frame` could help. But that's a hack that I would only use for debugging, not for productive use.